# noSuchMethod in globally defined functions

Tags: javascript

I am aware of `__noSuchMethod__` but I'm not sure how to get this for functions that are called like this.

```
someThing();
```

For example I am aware I can do this

```
var global = Function('return this')();
global.__noSuchMethod__ = function(id, args) {
  console.log('No Such Method');
}
global.notDefined();
```

But it does not work with this

```
var global = Function('return this')();
global.__noSuchMethod__ = function(id, args) {
  console.log('No Such Method');
}
notDefined();
```

As is quite obvious there is some Javascript fundamentals that I still need to learn.

What I am trying to accomplish is to catch functions that are called outside of an object. If that makes sense. I apologize if my terminology is a bit off.

Comment: This is non standard and doesn't have to behave like normal javascript.

Comment: Well Firefox at least doesn't seem to pay attention to `__noSuchMethod__` on the `window` object (and I'm not really surprised).

Comment: Oh ok. Are you aware of any way to accomplish this? I'm guessing no. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug in Firefox (I assume this is what you are testing on)

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=466239

Comment: You are the man. Thank you. Are you aware if there is a workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just use the "window" keyword whenever you are calling functions that may not exist?